# Role of different types of variables in a linear model

Tags: mixed-model, fixed-effects-model, instrumental-variables, endogeneity

In a package to write linear regression models I have found the following description:

`dependent variable ~ exogenous variables + (endogenous variables ~ instrumental variables) + fe(fixedeffect variable)`

Can you explain the role of the various type of variables, in particular the difference between endogenous and exogenous variables, the instrumental and the fixedeffects ones ?
Are there cases where all are used together ?

Comment: Isn't the endogenous variable the depenent variable in econometrics-speak? Which package has that line?

Comment: @Dave: https://github.com/FixedEffects/FixedEffectModels.jl